# How to take a snapshot of Token2022 holders?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token-program, token-2022, snapshot

How to take a snapshot of all holders of a Token2022? I get an output of 0

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const {PublicKey, Connection} = require('@solana/web3.js');
const {get} = require('lodash');

const connection = new Connection(process.env.RPC_HOST);

async function getTokenOwners(address, tokenDecimals) {
    // The value 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'
    // is the public key for the Solana Token Program.This program is a part of the Solana blockchain's ecosystem,
    // and it manages all SPL(Solana Program Library) token operations, including minting, transferring, and burning tokens.
    const TOKEN_PUBKEY = new PublicKey(
        'TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb'
    );

    const filters = [
        {
            memcmp: {
                offset: 0,
                bytes: address,
            },
        },
        {
            dataSize: 165,
        },
    ];
    const programAccountsConfig = {
        filters,
        encoding: 'jsonParsed',
    };
    const listOfTokens = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
        TOKEN_PUBKEY,
        programAccountsConfig
    );

    return listOfTokens
        .map((token) => {
            const address = get(token, 'account.data.parsed.info.owner');
            const amountString = get(
                token,
                'account.data.parsed.info.tokenAmount.amount'
            );
            const amount =
                parseInt(amountString, 10) / Math.pow(10, tokenDecimals);

            return {
                address,
                amount,
            };
        })
        .sort((a, b) => b.amount - a.amount);
}

async function main() {
    console.log('Getting token holders');

    const tokenAddress = 'EVoLsbmQXT6R3b11WjPpGEXyCjw1zmmir271XqDbKRsg';
    const tokenDecimals = 9;

    try {
        const owners = await getTokenOwners(tokenAddress, tokenDecimals);

        const outputFile = 'tokens-owner.json';
        fs.writeFileSync(
            path.resolve(outputFile),
            JSON.stringify(owners, null, 2)
        );

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error.message || error);
    }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 2):

The filters for token accounts are a bit off. With token-2022, token accounts can include optional "extensions", so their size is often going to be larger than 165 bytes. In fact, all associated-token-accounts use the "immutable owner" extensions, which adds another 5 bytes to the account size.

This means token accounts are either accounts with a length of 165, OR accounts with the number "2" as their 165th byte, so you can do:

```
const filters = [
        {
            memcmp: {
                offset: 0,
                bytes: address,
            },
        },
        {
            memcmp: {
                offset: 165,
                bytes: "3", // the number 2 as base58, which means AccountType::Account
            }
        },
    ];
```